# Unable to run 'gradle sonarqube' against SonarQube 5.3 installation

Tags: sonarqube

I have a fresh installation of `SonarQube v5.3` and am trying to run the `gradle` sonarqube plugin v1.2 against it with `'gradle sonarqube'`. Looking at the debug log, the plugin clearly reaches the sonarqube installation I reference in `~/.gradle/gradle.properties`, but is unable to get the bootstrap index:

```
[DEBUG] [org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask] cache: /Users/xxxx/.sonar/ws_cache/xxxxx900/global  [INFO] [org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask] User cache: /Users/xxxx/.sonar/cache  [DEBUG] [org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask] Extract sonar-runner-batch in temp... [DEBUG] [org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask] Get bootstrap index...  [DEBUG] [org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask] Download: http://xxxxx:9000/batch_bootstrap/index
```

Here is the stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Status returned by url [http://xxxxx:9000/batch_bootstrap/index] is not valid: [404]    at org.sonar.runner.impl.ServerConnection.callUrl(ServerConnection.java:186)    at org.sonar.runner.impl.ServerConnection.downloadString(ServerConnection.java:121)
```

It seems that URL should be `xxxxx:9000/**sonar**/batch_bootstrap/index` (which is a valid URL on my server). Is the lack of 'sonar' in that URL a bug? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` simply pass sonar.host.url=http://xxxxx:9000/**sonar**

Comment: Doh! I had tried that before but had an older version of SonarQube (v5.1.2) so there was some sort of a mismatch. Thanks. I'm back in business.

Answer (score 0):

In your project's gradle scripts, for the sonarqube task you can put

```
apply plugin: "org.sonarqube"

sonarqube {
    properties {
        property "sonar.host.url", "http://yourURL:9000"
    }
}
```

If your using a gradle wrapper, you can then use the command in a bash shell

```
./gradlew sonarqube
```

Or for a CMD

```
gradlew sonarqube
```